# Jenkins and Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am new to Jenkins. How Jenkins is helpful for a developer using Eclipse IDE? In simple, how to set up Continuous Integration with Eclipse and Jenkins?

Please guide me to a link where I can follow steps to set up Eclipse with Jenkins plugin and trigger builds from developer machine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are new to Jenkins Tutorials Point has a good tutorial that will guide you through the basics

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/

Jenkins also have a step-by-step guide

Plugin tutorial: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial

Using Eclipse with Jenkins: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Setting+up+Eclipse+to+build+Jenkins

Comment: Thanks. It helped!

Comment: I have tried the Eclipse plugin for Jenkins Pipeline, not very useful IMHO. It seems that in Intellij there is a far better support https://st-g.de/2016/08/jenkins-pipeline-autocompletion-in-intellij

Answer (score 2):

The critical connection you have to have is a build process, using either Gradle or Maven.  Once you can build your project from the command line using your build script, you can start to automate it in Jenkins.  If you don't have that build process yet, you won't be able to automate it with Jenkins.

You'll also need a source code management (SCM) system, like git or Subversion.  In general, you don't want to have to trigger builds manually, you want builds to trigger automatically when new code is checked into git or subversion.  Plugins in your SCM or in Jenkins can "watch" your code repository for new checkins, and spawn builds from that.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried something which actually worked for me and I think sharing the recipe will be helpful for the newbies to the DevOps-Development integrated environment.

Drag and drop [this](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/hudsonjenkins-mylyn-builds-connector#group-screenshots) plugin ([Hudson/Jenkins Mylyn Builds Connector](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/hudsonjenkins-mylyn-builds-connector#group-details)) in your Eclipse workspace and proceed with the installation process with Eclipse marketplace wizard. Once it is installed you will be asked to restart your Eclipse in order to reflect the new changes.

*If there is any issue installing the plugin then it means, plugins that you have are conflicting with the ones attempted to be installed. Once it computes the alternate paths, it pops up the next wizard page. You should be able to see what the conflicts are and choose one of the necessary actions.

Next, in you Eclipse IDE, go to Window ---> Show View ---> Other ---> Mylyn ---> Builds
Select Builds and click Open.

You will now see a Build page in your Eclipse IDE. Just go ahead and click on "Create a new build server". A new window will pop up, select Hudson(supports Jenkins) and click Next.

Copy paste your Jenkins server URL in the Server field and give it a name (Label), click Finish.
You will see your new build server under Builds. Right click on it ---> Plan ---> Open in browser.

This will open your Jenkins dashboard inside the Eclipse IDE. You will be able to perform any operation and trigger a Build pipeline job from here.